# Aframe state component - rendering assets

Tags: aframe

I'm wondering how to manage assets in aframe state component

In the example of a list

```
<a-entity bind-for="for: shoppingItem; in: shoppingList; key: name">
  <template>
    <a-entity bind__text="value: shoppingItem.name"
              data-amount="{{ shoppingItem.amount }}"></a-entity>
  </template>
</a-entity>
```

I assume you'd use something like this

```
      <a-assets bind-for="for: asset; in: assets; key: id">
        <template>
            <a-asset-item response-type="arraybuffer" bind__src="asset.src" bind__id="value: asset.id" />
        </template>
      </a-assets>
```

However that would only work for videos.

If I set my inital state as such

```
initialState: {
  hotspots: [],
  assets: [{src: 'https://example.com/assets/logo.png' , id: 'logo'}]
},
```

And plan on populating those asset arrays with the src and id of each asset, then SRC is not making it to the entity with the error:

> Cannot read property 'match' of null
>       at FileLoader.load (aframe-master.js:28912)
>       at HTMLElement.value (aframe-master.js:57743)
>       at HTMLElement.wrappedMethod (aframe-master.js:59621)

I tried `<a-asset-item response-type="arraybuffer" src="{{asset.id}}" bind__src="value: asset.src" bind__id="value: asset.id" />`

And that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind only works with entities. It does not make sense to use a run-time state binder with an asset **preloading** system.

`<a-entity bind__material="src: assetUrl">`

Comment: ahh OK so you can't preload assets dynamically using this system? I.e. I have a menu that preloads images, then that selects a 'game' which preloads assets.

Comment: There's kinda no such thing as preloading assets dynamically. Preload means it's downloaded before the scene runs and blocks the scene from rendering. Dynamically means while the scene is running. You can set the src url. You can set your own loading screen if you need and manually listen to asset loads if you need.